# Wordpress Plugin - event with 4 stream lines

Tags: wordpress, plugins, schedule

I would like to make a page of a 2 Days event schedule.
It has 4 stream lines.

I've searched for event plugins, but I can't find one does exactly what I want.

One session is about one hour and has a organiser, and 4 streamlines run from 9 to 5.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [**Question Checklist**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/). If you are looking for a plugin, then that is off topic for this website. If you are looking for the code or algorithm to do this, that is also off topic - this is not a coding or tutoring service, you are expected to have *researched your issue* and *made attempts to solve it* before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different plugins, this is the best one for me:

https://webnus.net/modern-events-calendar/

I think this website is used for exchanging information, before spending a lot of time.
I will post this answer for the people who might have the same question as me.